# Tracking Android App Install (non mobile Ads) with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

as subject,

I want to track Android App install, but I want to track any install and not just from mobile Ads. My question, is it possible?

One particular question is: If I run the development version of my app that in theory, is integrated with Facebook SDK, straight from IDE into an emulator, will I see it reflected in "Last Mobile Install" stats in my dashboard? Because apparently, it didn't. If it's not, is there any way to do this in a debug environment in order to confirm whether I'm using Facebook SDK correctly or not?

For reference, I'm calling this line in my `onResume()` method:

```
    com.facebook.AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, getString(R.string.facebook_application_id);
```

Thanks.

**Update**: So it's probably not a proper question. I concluded that Facebook recorded mobile installs from Android app based on its `attributionId`. If this value is null, such as if there's no Facebook app or it's not logged in, the mobile installs is simply not recorded. I think.